# Updating every X ms image source impacts the memory [memory leak]

Tags: javascript, html, memory-leaks

**The problem:**

When I want to update one image every 50ms and display it on screen (firefox, chrome), I noticed that the memory is growing up rapidly.

**What I have:**

- One server which serve a new image each time I call the request /carto (for example http://192.168.0.190:3000/carto?a=XXXXXX)
- I had this part ?a=XXXXXX ONLY to avoid the cache (otherwise the first image loaded will always be displayed). Adding ?a=XXXXXX (XXXXXXX is the timestamp) will not have any impact on the destination to reach

**My minimalist source code which calls every 50ms my server and display each loaded image:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" >
      function displayNextImage() {
        document.getElementById("img").src = `http://192.168.0.190:3000/carto?a=${new Date().getTime()}`
      }
      function startTimer() {
          setInterval(displayNextImage, 100);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="startTimer();">
    <p>Welcome to a problem</p>
    <img id="img" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**What are the results:**

- I notice the memory is growing rapidly

**What I would like to understand:**

- Why is this happening ?
- How to solve this problem which impacts all browsers ?

If you have any idea, don't hesitate to comment this post :)